counting calls decorator - why do I reset function attribute back to 0?
the code below counts the num times the decorated function func was called:
from functools import wraps

def counting_calls(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        inner.call_count += 1
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    inner.call_count = 0
    return inner

for this test:
@counting_calls
def add(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    '''return sum of 2 ints'''
    return a + b

print(add(10, b=20))
print(add(30, 5))
print(add(3, 5))
print(add(4, 5))
print('num calls =', add.call_count)
print(add(11, 5))
print('num calls =', add.call_count)

why do we reset inner.call_count = 0? does not it actually reset the call_count always to 0 and does not save the total num calls?

That's initializing it, not resetting it. inner doesn't have a call_count attribute until the inner.call_count = 0 initialization.
The initialization happens immediately after the inner function is created, not every time inner is called. inner.call_count += 1 happens every time inner is called, since it's in inner's body, but inner.call_count = 0 is outside of inner.

thx, this was at first hard to get ; now its clear
